# Trying to create a large dynamic query, keeps getting truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting, dynamic-sql

I have a SQL query in SQL server where I am trying to create large query with 'union' on a large number of databases. However, the query keeps getting truncated. According to my research this shouldn't happen if all the `varchar` are cast to `varchar(MAX)`.  I tried doing this, however, it still gets truncated. The final query should be in the `@finalQuery` varible. Can anyone help with the query below?

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(MAX) -- database name  
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(MAX) -- path for backup files  
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(MAX) -- filename for backup  
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(MAX) -- used for file name 
DECLARE @executeQuery VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @finalQuery VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @finalQuery = ''
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM master..sysdatabases
WHERE name NOT IN (CAST('master' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST('model' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST('msdb' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST('tempdb' AS VARCHAR(MAX)))  
OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @executeQuery=CAST(
 'SELECT TOP 1000 
       [EmailAddress] as ''Email Address''
      ,[FirstName] as ''First Name''
      ,[LastName] as ''Last Name''
      ,[LastLogin] as ''Last Login'',
        Name as ''User Role''
  FROM '+@name+'.[dbo].[User] c
  INNER JOIN 
  (  SELECT * FROM '+@name+'.[dbo].[SecurityRole] as a 
     INNER JOIN '+@name+'.[dbo].[SecurityRoleToUser] as b
     ON (a.ID=b.SecurityRoleID)
  ) d     
  ON (c.ID=d.UserID)
  WHERE IsActive=1' AS VARCHAR(MAX))

  --PRINT @executeQuery
  --PRINT @name
  --PRINT @executeQuery
  SET @finalQuery = CAST(@executeQuery+' UNION ALL ' +@finalQuery AS VARCHAR(MAX))
  --PRINT @executeQUery
    --EXEC (@executeQuery)
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name

END
CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
PRINT @finalQuery
--EXEC(@finalQuery)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'gets truncated' ? I see a limiting statement in your SQL.

Comment: I mean that the @@finalQuery variable does not include everything in the loop. What do you mean by 'limiting statement'?

Comment: use varchar(somevalue) instead of varchar(max)..for example use varchar(4000) which will be sufficient

Comment: I saw the select top 1000 - I didn't know if that was what you meant.

Comment: Ah, that's fine. I mean that the variable @finalQuery gets truncated.

Comment: why don't you try PRINT CAST(@finalQuery AS TEXT)?

Comment: How do you know it gets truncated? If you are looking at that value in SSMS it will truncate, that is how SSMS works. If you think it is longer than SSMS will display you need to output that value to another table or a text file so you can see the whole thing.

Comment: Why not SELECT INTO a temp table within the cursor and then SELECT * FROM temp table at the end.

Comment: Why not just do it in a select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off without doing a `UNION` across so many databases. And you don't need to. Also, database names, etc are all `sysname` which equates to `NVARCHAR(128)` so best to use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead of `VARCHAR(MAX)`.

**Step 1: Less complicated query generation**

```sql
DECLARE @DatabaseName sysname;

DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Template NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Query = '';
SET @Template = N'USE [?];
       SELECT TOP 1000 
       [EmailAddress] as [Email Address]
      ,[FirstName] as [First Name]
      ,[LastName] as [Last Name]
      ,[LastLogin] as [Last Login],
        Name as [User Role]
  FROM [dbo].[User] c
  INNER JOIN 
  (  SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SecurityRole] as a 
     INNER JOIN [dbo].[SecurityRoleToUser] as b
     ON (a.ID=b.SecurityRoleID)
  ) d     
  ON (c.ID=d.UserID)
  WHERE IsActive = 1;

';

SELECT @Query = (@Query + REPLACE(@Template, N'?', sd.[name]))
FROM   sys.databases sd
WHERE  sd.[name] NOT IN (N'master', N'model', N'msdb', N'tempdb')
AND    HAS_DBACCESS(sd.[name]) = 1;

--EXEC(@Query); -- uncomment when not debugging

SELECT LEN(@Query); -- 9506 on my system -- comment out if debugging
print @query; -- truncates at 4000 chars for NVARCHAR -- comment out if debugging
```

**Step 2: Not needing a UNION**

Instead of using a UNION to get everything into a single result set, just insert multiple result sets into a local temporary table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #tmp (DatabaseName sysname NOT NULL,
                   EmailAddress NVARCHAR(200), FirstName NVARCHAR(50),
                   LastName NVARCHAR(50), LastLogin DATETIME, UserRole VARCHAR(50);

DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Template NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Query = '';
SET @Template = N'USE [?];
       SELECT TOP 1000
       DB_NAME() AS [DatabaseName],
       [EmailAddress] as [Email Address]
      ,[FirstName] as [First Name]
      ,[LastName] as [Last Name]
      ,[LastLogin] as [Last Login],
        Name as [User Role]
  FROM [dbo].[User] c
  INNER JOIN 
  (  SELECT UserID, Name--* -- see Step #3 below
     FROM [dbo].[SecurityRole] sr
     INNER JOIN [dbo].[SecurityRoleToUser] srtu
             ON sr.ID = srtu.SecurityRoleID
  ) d     
         ON c.ID = d.UserID
  WHERE IsActive = 1;

';

SELECT @Query = (@Query + REPLACE(@Template, N'?', sd.[name]))
FROM   sys.databases sd
WHERE  sd.[name] NOT IN (N'master', N'model', N'msdb', N'tempdb')
AND    HAS_DBACCESS(sd.[name]) = 1;

INSERT INTO #tmp (DatabaseName, EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName, LastLogin, UserRole)
  EXEC(@Query);

SELECT * FROM #tmp;
```

**Step 3:**

It is probably best not use `SELECT *` in your `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SecurityRole] as a` subquery. Just select the fields that you need as it will be more likely to use indexes. It looks like you just need two fields: `UserID, Name`

Comment: This looks good, I like 'Step 2', I think the results are correct but I am also getting a syntax error. Any chance you can tell me how to add a column to the result set with the name of the database that the given row came from?

Comment: @ArtF What is the exact error you are getting? I have updated the code in **Step 2** to include the DB name (and to include the suggestion made in **Step 3**, and removed the unused `@DatabaseName` variable declaration), but you won't ever see that if there is a syntax error in the code.

Comment: Its fine, there are some other databases that I have to skip. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's `PRINT` that gets truncated, not your variable:

From the docs on [`PRINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx):

> A message string can be up to 8,000 characters long if it is a non-Unicode string, and 4,000 characters long if it is a Unicode string. Longer strings are truncated. The `varchar(max)` and `nvarchar(max)` data types are truncated to data types that are no larger than `varchar(8000)` and `nvarchar(4000)`.

Answer (score 0):

why use a cursor?

```
SELECT 
'SELECT TOP 1000 
       [EmailAddress] as ''Email Address''
      ,[FirstName] as ''First Name''
      ,[LastName] as ''Last Name''
      ,[LastLogin] as ''Last Login'',
        Name as ''User Role''
  FROM ' + name + '.[dbo].[User] c' 
  .....
FROM master..sysdatabases
WHERE name NOT IN (CAST('master' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST('model' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST('msdb' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CAST('tempdb' AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
```

Comment: the op wants to gather these statements into `@finalQuery` for dynamic execution.